# LIKE does not work in MYSQL when the syntax is correct

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
public ResultSet getResourcesById(String id, String type)
{
    try {
        conn = connect();
        selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + type + "WHERE ID LIKE ?";
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "%ba%");
        res = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        return res;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CatalogDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hi all. I'm using java in my system. I have tried to put in an arbitary String but it keeps on telling me this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%ba%'' at
>   line 1

Can someone explain to me why is there this error, I'm pretty sure I followed the syntax correctly.

Comment: It is saying the error is near there. I would suspect the error is actually due to the table name passed in type. Possibly due to needing a space before the WHERE

Comment: BTW, try to avoid statements like "LIKE does not work in MySQL", "if does not work in Java" etc. Like works in MySQL. Java works too. We, application programmers sometimes write buggy code.

Comment: What datatype is the `ID` column? It does not make any sense using like on a number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is not on the `LIKE`. You have just missed one extra space before the `WHERE` clause.

```
selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + type + " WHERE ID LIKE ?";
                                             ^  add space here
```